# Maximum voting bug?

Tags: support, voting

I always tend to hit my maximum vote cap of 40 every day. They are not spam votes, but actual votes for good questions and answers as I tend to spend a good part of my day on the site.

Now, as one can see, I have hit 36 votes, and seeing that the normal cap is 40, I should still have 4 more votes, but when I try to vote, it says I have reached the maximum number of votes for the day.

[image]

Why do I not have 4 more votes left?

Comment: had reported this earlier - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90058/daily-vote-limit-hit-before-reaching-actual-counts seems it's come up again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal daily vote cap is not constantly 40. *It depends how many questions you voted for.*

https://superuser.com/faq#reputation

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, **to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions.**

The relevant part is bolded.

Comment: It's not possible to vote on questions when there are 0 votes left, even though one hasn't reached 40 yet. Your quote doesn't actually mention this behavior. That's what happened to me yesterday with 37 votes. I was no longer able to vote on questions either.

Comment: @Daniel Same thing happened with me, could not vote on questions. I guess once you hit the **"limit"** without voting on 10 questions first, there's no way to use the remaining votes on questions.